# Why do I get a NullPointerException on getDir?

Tags: java, android, file

I understood that getDir will create a directory if it doesnt exist yet. But I'm crashing on:

```
File dir= getDir(file,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

file is of type String. logcat shows:

```
12-29 21:56:09.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(631): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 21:56:09.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(631):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDir(ContextWrapper.java:198)
```

Here's the code:

```
public class ReportHome extends Application{
public ReportHome(String message, String file){
    …some code…
    inf(tosend,file);
}
public void inf(String c, String file){
    File dir= getDir(file,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

btw: what is the trick to format more than one line of logcat correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that the `file` argument isn't null?

If it's not, then the other possibility is that you're not running this in a sane environment.

Looking at the [source code for getDir()](http://www.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/content/ContextWrapper.java&q=android.content.ContextWrapper.java%20getDir&type=cs&l=196), the only other possibility is that `mBase` (a private variable that holds the current `Context`) is null. I'm not quite sure how that would happen without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: I expanded the answer a bit then. Is there some reason there wouldn't be a valid Context based on where this is? (Is this inside of an Activity, or somewhere else?)

Answer (score 1):

Do not implement a constructor on any component, including `Application`. Move this logic to `onCreate()`, after you have called `super.onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

The getDir() method in itself isn't very interesting, as it just delegates the call to its underlying `Context` object (as with about every call to the `ContextWrapper`).

```
@Override
public File getDir(String name, int mode) {
    return mBase.getDir(name, mode);
}
```

It's important to know where you're calling the method from. `mBase` is set when the constructor of `ContextWrapper` is called or with `attachBaseContext()`. If you're certain that `file` isn't `null`, it appears as if neither of the the former to paths have been taken. Can you verify that the context you're working on isn't actually `null` by printing/debugging the returned result for `getBaseContext()`?

Comment: it's the context. I added Context to the constructor and use it for doing getDir and things are working fine now.
Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed only after posting that Trevor editted his original answer to basically include what I was saying, sorry 'bout that.