# context.getdir() NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have written a simple code

```
if (context != null) 
    {
        File mydir = context.getDir("abc",0);
    }
```

As per my understanding, i can pass any random string as the first parameter.
This will be name of the directory created. 
Also this code is already inside null check, so context cannot be null.

but this is giving NullPointerException

```
11-10 09:43:44.839: E/AndroidRuntime(11441): FATAL EXCEPTION: DOWNLOAD_THREAD
11-10 09:43:44.839: E/AndroidRuntime(11441): Process: com.samsung.samsunggearapps, PID: 11441
11-10 09:43:44.839: E/AndroidRuntime(11441): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 09:43:44.839: E/AndroidRuntime(11441):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDir(ContextWrapper.java:257)
```

EDIT: I tried using getApplicationContext(); . Even that is null.

```
11-10 11:31:17.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21038): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 11:31:17.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21038):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:114)
```

Comment: use getApplicationContext() instead of context.

Comment: Can you show how you obtain your ```Context``` object?

Comment: Context context = getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 1):

I think you cant do that. You must specify `where` (1st param) and `how` (2nd param):

```
File mydir = context.getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: the second parameter can be 0. Even if i give Context.MODE_PRIVATE, i get the same error.

Comment: @user4057066 Yes, what really annoying me is the 1st param..why you do that?

Comment: even if I change my code to if (context != null) { File mydir = context.getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);}, i get the same error. It is not going in else also. which means context is not null.

Comment: @user4057066 Now...that is strange. I never got that problem, take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673567/why-do-i-get-a-nullpointerexception-on-getdir

Answer (score 0):

getDir() enables you to create any file or directory in the internal memory, which is also accessible by other applications depending on the mode you create.

```
File dir = ctx.getDir("abc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is the right thing to do?  Code dumping without any explanation is usually discouraged here on StackOverflow.