# calling exists on directory always return false in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a directory in internal storage for my app. Following is the code I am using to check if the directory exists or not. If the directory already exists, it is returned; else, the directory is created and returned. But even in the subsequent calls to the method, the exists() call on the directory always return false. What is the reason? Thanks

```
public File getMessageVoiceDirectory() {
    File messageVoiceDirectory = this.myContext.getDir("Voice",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    if (messageVoiceDirectory.exists() == false) {
        messageVoiceDirectory.mkdirs();
    }


    return messageVoiceDirectory;
}
```

Comment: @pratim- check the path you are getting from "this.myContext.getFilesDir()".. by debbugging...

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  use this..if you are getting wrong path

Answer (score 0):

First off, switch your condition to

```
if (!messageVoiceDirectory.exists()) {
    boolean actuallyCreated = messageVoiceDirectory.mkdirs();
    if (!actuallyCreated){
       Log.e("Activity", "Woah... the mkdirs command got called, but was not successful. We need to investigate.");
    }
}
```

Next, you need to check the return value of `mkdirs`. Presumably the directory isn't being created. This could happen if you don't have the correct permissions.

Comment: do you think this answers the question about ***why the method always return false***??

Comment: It might help to show an example of checking the result of `mkdirs()` and taking some appropriate action for the failure case.  Otherwise readers may overlook the most important half of the answer!

Comment: You dont need any permission for internal files dir.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. It will work

```
 File path = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "DirectoryName");
     if (!path.exists()) {
         path.mkdirs();
         Toast.makeText(this,"Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     else
         Toast.makeText(this,"Already Exist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Your first toast should check the return value of mkdirs.

Answer (score 0):

When you exactly call `getMessageVoiceDirectory()`, ensure that you call inside onCreate(),

- Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673908/1283715) out.